# error in Keras: Invalid argument 'metrics' passed to K.function

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I am working on some problems about machine learning and want to try the powerful package Keras(using Theano backend) in python. While I am running a demo of MLP for digit recognition [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py), it gives the follow error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mlp.py", line 52, in <module>
metrics=['accuracy'])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 564, in compile
updates=updates, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 459, in function
raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Invalid argument 'metrics' passed to K.function
```

I don't know why it gave the error message, can anyone help me to fix the bug? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means that you are running Keras version 0 (e.g. 0.3.2) but running code that was written for Keras version 1.  You can upgrade to Keras 1, or remove `metrics=['accuracy']` from the function call to `model.compile()`.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Keras are you running?

I updated (e.g., "pip install --upgrade keras"), and that keyword is now accepted.

Take care, however, because several other functions have changed. For example, if you would like to access layer input and output after training, the model method functions have changed.

see http://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/

Comment: Well, I just delete the syntax with keyword 'metrics'  and it works well~. thank you