# ValueError: Invalid argument 'metric' passed to K.function even with newest Keras/Theano

Tags: python, neural-network, anaconda, theano, keras

When I run the following very simple neural network in Anaconda / Python2.7 / Keras / Theano:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

# import csv
csv = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uiuc-cse/data-fa14/gh-pages/data/iris.csv'
iris = np.genfromtxt(csv, delimiter = ',', dtype = None)

# Munge data
iris = np.delete(iris, 0, 0)  # delete header row
iris[iris[:,4] == 'setosa', 4] = 1
iris[(iris[:,4] == 'versicolor') | (iris[:,4] == 'virginica'), 4] = 0
iris = iris.astype(float)

# split into data and label classes
data = iris[:,0:4]
labels = iris[:,4]
labels = np.array([labels])
labels = labels.T
labels = labels.astype(int)

# develop NN
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim = 4))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metric = ['accuracy'])

# fit NN
model.fit(data, labels, nb_epoch = 5, batch_size = 50)
```

I receive the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\bAXTER\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\theano_backend.py", line 539, in function
    raise ValueError(msg)

ValueError: Invalid argument 'metric' passed to K.function
```

I looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812548/error-in-keras-invalid-argument-metrics-passed-to-k-function), but I am already using Keras 1.0.5 and Theano 0.9.0 on Anaconda (Python 2.7) with all relevant packages installed.  In addition, the post mentions that I can "remove `metrics=['accuracy']` from the function call to `model.compile()`". but I cannot find either of those terms in 'theano_backend.py'.  I was not able to comment on that user's answer because I do not have enough reputation.

Any ideas on why keras is causing this error?  I know this is a less explored area of python so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Very embarrassing. I spelled `metric` instead of `metrics` in the `model.compile` command.

Comment: I think this is a version issue. This: https://en.hsmouc.com/2017/04/01/2017-04-01-regressionbykeras/ tutorial has "metric" as the spelling.